# SQL Server Latin Accent Sensitive collation

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, collation

I have a following query

```
select T.[KEY] Id,  T.[RANK]  Score, D.Name,
CASE 
            WHEN D.Name = 'će' THEN 1000        
            WHEN D.Name  COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS LIKE 'će%' THEN 500       
            WHEN D.Name  LIKE 'će%' THEN 100        
            ELSE 10 
END MatchType
from containstable(Dishes, (Name), '("će*")', language 0x0, 15) as T
INNER JOIN Dishes D On T.[KEY] = D.DishId
ORDER BY MatchType Desc, Score Desc
```

And it produces following result:

[image]

Can someone tell me why "Ćevapi" does not have Match score of 500 in this case? According to Collation it should?

The point here is to prioritize `će` over `ce` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're converting the string literal to varchar.

Bad:

```
select 1 
where N'Ćevapi' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS LIKE 'će%'
```

Good:

```
select 1 
where N'Ćevapi' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS LIKE N'će%'
```